# iOS8 UIImagePickerController in custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, camera, keyboard, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm experimenting with trying to have an embedded camera within an iOS8 custom keyboard extension that has Full Access enabled.  Everything works as I'd expect except the embedded UIImagePickerController's view is always black except for the overlay controls.  The "this app would like to access your camera" popup displays and access is definitely granted (triple-checked).

In XCode, `[UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]` returns true, and the UIImagePickerController's interface aside from the camera itself displays properly (e.g., camera overlay controls).

The only error / warning I'm getting from XCode is the following:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

I've tried adding timeouts to the initialization of the camera as several other stackoverflow threads have suggested, but nothing I do fixes that warning or the black camera screen issue.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(loadCamera) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}

- (void)loadCamera
{
self._picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

self._picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self._picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self._picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self._picker.allowsEditing = NO;
self._picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
self._picker.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

self._picker.delegate = self;

self._picker.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:self._picker.view];
[self._picker didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

I've also tried replacing the last 3 lines with the following with the same result:

```
[self presentViewController:self._picker animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"completed");
}];
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to embed a UIImagePickerController within an iOS8 custom keyboard extension, and if so, what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, access to camera or microphone is not possible in extensions.

See duplicate thread here with link to the Apple doc: [iOS Custom Keyboard - camera not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957524/ios-custom-keyboard-camera-not-working).